# How can I split a row without spaces in a txt to do a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, split

I have this txt:

```
1989MaiteyCarlos
2015mamasypadres
```

And I have a code to separate word and generate different columns to DataFrame.
The code is:

```
txt1=pd.read_table(r'C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\prueba.txt',header=None)

txt1['anno'] = txt1[0].apply(lambda x: x[:4])
txt1['chica'] = txt1[0].apply(lambda x: x[4:9])
txt1['chico'] = txt1[0].apply(lambda x: x[10:])
```

I need to do a general function to solved the problem. I tried it with this code:

```
def read_txt (df,columnas,rangos):
    for i,j in zip(columnas,rangos):
        for k in j:
            df[i] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x[k])
    return df
```

But the result was fail.

How can I do this function?

Comment: How sure are you that the data is always between those ranges? @Maite89

Comment: Is only an example. I chose those ranges.

Comment: What I'm asking here is that whether those ranges will vary across rows?

Comment: no all rows have the same ranges.

Comment: A delimiter is always good for text data. This problem should be fixed at source rather than juggling with bad data. If you fix the ranges then the problem is that if you get a string with longer characters it will be put into another column

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
the function that I used is:

```
def read_txt (df,columnas,rangos):
    for i,j in zip(columnas,rangos):
        df[i] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x[j[0]:j[1]])
    return df

data = read_txt (txt1,['anno','chica','chico'],[[0,4],[4,9],[10,16]])
```